# $\mathcal I(X\cap Y)=\mathcal I(X)+\mathcal I(Y)$ for algebraic sets

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to prove that $\mathcal I(X\cap Y)=\mathcal I(X)+\mathcal I(Y)$ for algebraic sets $X, Y$.

I was able to prove $\mathcal I(X)+\mathcal I(Y)\subseteq \mathcal I(X\cap Y)$:

Let $f\in\mathcal I(X)+\mathcal I(Y)$. Then $f=g+h$, $g\in\mathcal I(X),h\in\mathcal I(Y)\iff f=g+h, g(a)=0\;\forall\, a\in X, h(b)=0\;\forall\, b\in Y$, so $f(c)=g(c)+h(c)=0\;\forall\, c\in X\cap Y\implies f\in\mathcal I(X\cap Y).$

I'm not sure how to prove the other contention. Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is $\mathcal I$?

Comment: $\mathcal I(X)$ is the set of polynomials that are zero in every point of $X$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is not true. Consider $X=\{x\in\Bbb C^2\,:\, x_1=0\}$ and $Y=\{x\in\Bbb C^2\,:\, x_1-x_2^2=0\}$. Then, \begin{align}&\mathcal I(X)=(x_1)\\ &\mathcal I(Y)=(x_1-x_2^2)\\&\mathcal I(X)+\mathcal I(Y)=(x_1,x_2^2)\\ &\mathcal I(X\cap Y)=(x_1,x_2)\end{align}